# Given a rectangular matrix of characters, add a border of asterisks(*) to it

Tags: java, arrays, string

Example
For

```
picture = ["abc",
           "ded"]
```

the output should be

```
addBorder(picture) = ["*****",
                      "*abc*",
                      "*ded*",
                      "*****"]
```

I tried to another array and append the '*' ith elements

```
for (int i=0; i<arrlen+2; i++)
    if(i==0 || i==arrlen+1){
        for(int j = 0; j<len+2; j++)
            pictures[i] = pictures[i].append("*")
```

and

```
else {
        for(int j = 0; j<len+2; j++)
            if(j==0 || i==len+1)
                pictures[i] = pictures[i].append("*");
```

But it says "cannot find symbol" at the .append()

Comment: Please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and your complete stack trace.

Comment: What type is `pictures`? I think it's a custom type and don't have method `append`  so getting error.

Comment: I think `pictures` is a `String[]`. And a `String` doesn't have an `append` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this without using `.append`. Use a `for` loop to print a row of asterisks, which should be the length of the string plus 2(1 extra for each side). To get the length of the string use `.length()`Then print an asterisk before and after the string using

`System.out.println("*" + string + "*");`

and print the same row of asterisks as in the first part.

The same goes for printing an array of strings, just use a for loop to print each value with  `System.out.println("*" + string[i] + "*");` then follow it with the same row of asterisks used for the top border.

---

Edit: After reading your question again closely I think you wanted the result stored in a new array. I started writing an example code and couldn't help but write the whole thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text [] = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"};
    String framedString [] = {"","","","","","",""}; //java arrays are fixed in size, 
                                                     //so I had to define 6 blank values
    String asterisks = "**";
    int lineCounter = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < text[1].length(); i++) { //creates string of asterisks
        asterisks = asterisks + "*";
    }
    
    framedString[lineCounter] = asterisks; //first value becomes asterisk string
    
    for (int j = 0; j < text.length; j++) { //adds an asterisk before and after each string of "text" and stores it in "framedString"
        lineCounter = j+1;
        framedString[lineCounter] = "*" + text[j] + "*";
    }
    
    framedString[lineCounter+1] = asterisks; // last value becomes asterisk string as well
    
    for (int k = 0; k < framedString.length; k++) { //prints the result
        System.out.println(framedString[k]);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Well that is the problem, I am not trying to print them directly but append and store it into a separate array and then use that arraylist later.

Comment: @Shivangi My edit stores the words into an array that can be used later, `framedString`

Answer (score 1):

This solution can be broken down into 3 simple steps, 1st is to add the list of * at the top of the array, 2nd to add the * at the start and end of the element in the picture array by looping via the elements of the array and the last part is to add the list of * to the bottom of the array as the length of the last element of the array.

```
let picture =  ["abc", "ded"]; 

function addBorder(picture) {
 //adding the * on the top of the picture array as equal to the lenght of the top element of the array.
 let top = '*'.repeat(picture[0].length);
 picture.unshift(top);

 //looping through the array and concat the * at the end and the start of the array
 for(let i = 0; i < picture.length; i++){
     picture[i] = picture[i] + '*';
     picture[i] = '*' + picture[i];
 }

 //adding the * on the bottom of the picture array as equal to the lenght of the last element of the array.
 let bottom = '*'.repeat(picture[1].length);
 picture.push(bottom);
 
 return picture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] addBorder(String[] picture) {
final int additionalCount = 2;
int elementLength = picture[0].length() + additionalCount;  // first element length which used to determine howmany * required.
int loopLength = picture.length + additionalCount; // extra two iteration for loop to add *** at the begining and end of array.

String [] output = new String[loopLength];

String border = "";
for( int i = 1; i <= elementLength; i++){
    border += "*";
}

for (int i = 0; i < loopLength; i++){
    if(i == 0){
        output[i] = border;
    } else if(i == loopLength-1){
         output[i] = border;
    } else {
        String s = "*"+picture[i-1]+"*";
        output[i] = s;
    }
}
return output;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function addBorder(picture) {
  let maxlength = 0
  for (let i=0;i<picture.length;i++){
    if(picture[i].length>maxlength){
      maxlength= picture[i].length
    }
  }
  let border = "*".repeat(maxlength+2);
  let resultArr =[border,border]
for (let i=0;i<picture.length;i++){
    resultArr.splice(i+1,0,"\*"+picture[i]+"\*")
} return resultArr
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(picture) {
const verticalBorder = '*'.repeat(picture[0].length);
picture.unshift(verticalBorder);
picture.push(verticalBorder);
return picture.map( (el) => '*' + el + '*' );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function addBorder(picture) {
  const wall = "*".repeat(picture[0].length + 2);

  picture.unshift(wall);
  picture.push(wall);

  for (let i = 1; i < picture.length - 1; i++) {
    picture[i] = `*${picture[i]}*`;
  }
  return picture;
}

console.log(addBorder(["abc", "def", "ghi"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(picture) {
    let len=picture[0].length;
    let toReturnArray=[];
    toReturnArray[0]='*'.repeat(len+2);
    for(let i=0;i<picture.length;i++){
        toReturnArray.push(`${'*'+picture[i]+'*'}`);
    }
    toReturnArray.push(toReturnArray[0]);
    return toReturnArray;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).